# Using Google Cloud Functions API as Service Discovery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, microservices, google-cloud-functions

We're working on developing a microservice based architecture employing Google Cloud Functions.

We've developed a few functions and want to implement a discovery service.  This discovery service would be used to determine if a specific function exists and is operational.

The service discovery itself is a cloud function.  It makes a rest request to the below API and succeeds in local development using functions emulator and the default application credentials.

Google provides an API for this [https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/projects.locations.functions/get][1]

When deployed to production we're receiving:
{ "code": 401, "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.", "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED" } }

Cloud functions are stateless so there's no option to use a service account that I can see.  How do I go about authenticating a cloud function to call the functions api to determine if a function is available?

Below is how we've accomplished this in a local dev environment:

```
var options = {
    method: 'get',
    uri: `https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects/${config.PROJECT_ID}/locations/${config.LOCATION_ID}/functions/${functionName}`
  }

  console.log (options.uri);
  request(options, function (err, res, body) {
    if (!err && res.status === 200) {
      if(typeof res.body.httpsTrigger.url !== undefined) {
        console.log('found a function');
        return cb(false, res.body.httpsTrigger.url);
      }
      else {
        console.log('no function found, looking for static content');
        return cb(true, `Service doesn't exist, returned ${res.status}`)
      }
    }
    else {
      console.log('no function found, looking for static content'); 
      return cb(true, `Service doesn't exist, returned ${res.status}`);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API you mention contains method: projects.locations.functions.get , that requires one of the following OAuth scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudfunctions

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
```

You may have a look at the [Authentication in HTTP Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/authentication-in-http-cloud-functions) online document.

Comment: So if I add one of the above scopes to the service account under which that function is running it should then be able to call the API?

Comment: Feeling really dense about this. So, this cloud function, is calling the APIs to look at other cloud functions availability. 

Whether using a rest request or the api libraries, an OAuth2 token is expected.  Service accounts require a key file.  Cloud Functions have no storage, although perhaps Cloud Storage is an option?

Answer (score 1):

So I finally figured out how to do this. It's a bit of hack:.

1. Download the JSON Key file for the Service Account.
2. Add the JSON file to the Function source.
3. Install the google-auth-library NPM module.
4. Modify the request to use the client from google-auth-library

   ```
   const keys = require('./VirtualAssistantCred.json');
   ```

   const {auth} = require('google-auth-library');
     const client = auth.fromJSON(keys);
     client.scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'];
     client.authorize().then(function () {
         const url = `https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects/${config.PROJECT_ID}/locations/${config.LOCATION_ID}/functions/${functionName}`;
         client.request({url}, function(err, res) {
           if (err) {
             console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
             return cb(true, `Service, ${functionName} doesn't exist, returned ${res}`)
           } else { 
             console.log(`RESPONSE: ${JSON.stringify(res.data)}`);
             console.log(`Found Service at ${res.data.httpsTrigger.url}`);
             return cb(false, res.data.httpsTrigger.url); 
           }
         });
       }
     );